Index '0' is out of range in Power Automate
Not sure why I am running into this all of a sudden. Below is the error message in its entirety. The error is happening within another flow that is making a call to another.
Correlation Id: 74ac51be-e137-4cef-b09b-c66964b123f6
Index '0' is out of range.: Index '0' is out of range.
Set Variable Image
Tried changing the value of [0]. Removed the [0] entirely. Neither have worked.

it's not clear what you are trying to do. you have a loop through matches but then you take the first value from a table? are there values in the table?
